# What "determines" a specific quantum theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, foundations

I'm trying to give a bare bones description of non-relativistic quantum mechanics, for mathematicians. A description of the mathematical machinery. It is meant to answer to the questions:

- What makes a quantum theory?
- What make two quantum theories equivalent?

I purposefully leave out anything about measurement. This might be
naive, but I think it still works.

**My questions are**:

- Are the description and/or its conclusion (both below) very wrong?
- And if not very wrong, what are its limitations?

So here is my attempt:

> Take a Hilbert space H.
>
> "States" are equivalence classes of rays in H.
>
> "Observables" are linear transformations on H that are self-adjoint
>   (Hermitian) with respect to the inner-product.
>
> Predictions can only depend on
>
> 1. Absolute values of inner-products of
>      normalized states,
> 2. Traces of observables. (Using a Schauder basis)
>
> Conclusion: A quantum mechanics theory is determined by
>
> 1. The Hilbert
>      space,
> 2. The commutation relations of the observables.

Comment: How does your conclusion follow?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure that it does. My non-rigorous reasoning was that Hermitian operators can generate a Lie algebra, but not an algebra, since compositions of Hermitian operators are not necessarily Hermitian, but commutators are. Lie algebras are determined by their commutation relations (right?). 

So vague idea was that: 
if some observables could be mapped to some other observables that operate differently on the Hilbert space, but that map preserved the commutation relations, then the theory would work the same.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: @lalala In fact I would consider any clarification as to why this conclusion does not follow, as an answer to my question.

Comment: For reference, here are two different questions: ($Q1$) What are the general principles of quantum theory? In other words, how are the mathematical ingredients _used_ to make predictions? ($Q2$) After we understand what the general principles are, how do we specify a specific model? Answering $Q1$ without referring to measurement is impossible, so I assume that you're only looking for an way to answer $Q2$. Is that correct? In other words, are you looking for a definition of the "equivalence" of two models, both of which respect the general principles of quantum theory?

Comment: Thank you for your comment about measurement. I now see that indeed $Q2$ is what I really want to know. Anything towards answering that would be greatly appreciated.